# Embedding machine learning model in shiny web app

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny, reticulate

I would like to return predictions based on a model I built on a shiny web app.

These are the features I used to build the model

```
   weight height reach record opp_weight opp_height opp_reach opp_record
```

I am using these features to predict the outcome (win, loss,draw)

I am struggling to figure out how to load the model I built into my shiny web app in order to return predictions based on user selections

```
   boxing <- boxing[!is.na(boxing$name), ]
   #reading model
   p <- import("pandas")
   cat_model <- p$read_pickle("catmodel.pkl")
   ...
   uiOutput("Names")
   ...
   uiOutput("Opponent")
   ...
   actionButton("gobutton","Predict"),
   dataTableOutput("predictions")
   #server function
   output$predictions <- renderDataTable({
       cat_model$predict(input$names,input$names2) #names = name selected and outputted in "Names",names2 = name selected and outputted in "Opponent"
     })
```

This is a sample of the data in boxing

```
   name    division
   felix     a
   joe       a
   frazer    b
```

I understand that I do not have a names feature, as in, I do not parse the names or opponent names as a feature in my model, but can't for the life of me figure out what steps I would need to take to produce my desired result.

I assume I would need to merge my ML model with my original dataset (with the names and opponent names plus the features I used for the model)? But not sure if this makes sense

Comment: What package are you using? This looks like a mix of R and python code.

Comment: I am using the reticulate package in order to use some python code to get my model. The model is built on Python @Rohit

Comment: Basically, you need to create a one row dataframe with the same columns as your model features. So you get the rows in `boxer` corresponding to `input$names` and `input$names2`. Then, you get the features for both and concatenate them. You may have to rename the result based on your model.